# CakePHP v3.x API prefixed routes

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I have fallowing routes:

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
  Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
    $routes->resources('JobChemicals');
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute'); 
});
```

Url: /api/job_chemicals/2.json - WORKS
Url: /api/job-chemicals/2.json - NOT

Action JobChemicalsController::2() could not be found, or is not accessible. Why?! I am using DashdRoute not underscored. Any ideas? I know it is small thinks, but it makes me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

> `$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');`

This only affects the *fallback* routes, not the call to `$routes->resources`.

### Resource routes default to underscores

As noted in the question, underscored urls work.

As also [noted in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#url-inflection-for-resource-routes), resource routes default to underscores:

> By default, multi-worded controllers’ URL fragments are the underscored form of the controller’s name. E.g., BlogPostsController‘s URL fragment would be /blog_posts.
>
> You can specify an alternative inflection type using the inflect option:
>
> ```
> Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
>     $routes->resources('BlogPosts', [
>         'inflect' => 'dasherize' // Will use ``Inflector::dasherize()``
>     ];
> });
> ```
>
> The above will generate URLs styled like: /blog-posts/*.

The reason for this discrepancy is legacy (in 3.0 underscores were the default url inflection for everything), but the fix is simple - just include the `inflect` option to the resources call.